# add godaddy domain to AWS Elastic Beanstalk site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have a working web app hosted on Elastic Beanstalk and have purchased a domain name on godaddy.

I've got it set up so when you visit the domain it takes you to the correct page but the URL changes to the ugly elastic beanstalk address.

At the moment when I visit the domain name URL, the URL changes to

```
uglyurl.5345435trgfdg.elasticbeanstalk.com/CORRECT/ROUTES
```

I want it like

```
mydomain.com/CORRECT/ROUTES
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure whatever software you are running on Elastic Beanstalk (Apache or Nginx probably) to be aware of the domain name. The server software is simply redirecting all requests to the only domain it knows it is hosting.